# NSDictionary add -objectAtIndex by category

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary, categories

I'm writing custom patch for Quartz Composer and I work with structures as input. Structure are NSDictionary in Obj-C so I use NSDictionary's methods to deal with these structures. Depending on how I build these structures key can be NSString type or NSNumber.

Usually QC doesn't give named structures and keys are "0"..."n" or 0...n so I've decided to add -objectAtIndex in a NSDictionary category :

NSDictionary+Utils.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDictionary (Utils)

- (id)objectAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;

@end
```

NSDictionary+Utils.m

```
#import "NSDictionary+Utils.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (Utils)

- (id)objectAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSString* key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", index];
    return [self objectForKey:key];
}

@end
```

It works perfectly for one of my project in which I build a structure using Kineme Struc Maker patch.
In another project I use the Queue patch provided by apple. Keys are not NSString type but NSNumber type. I've rewritten the code to be compliant with NSNumber keys :

NSDictionary+Utils.m

```
@implementation NSDictionary (Utils)

- (id)objectAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSNumber* key = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:index];
    return [self objectForKey:key];
}

@end
```

Unfortunately it always gives a null value but using :

```
[self.inputSoundStruct objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]]
```

Why does this line of code works but not objectAtIndex ? I must be missing something but what ?

Comment: Is it possible that you’ve added both category versions to your project? In that case, which category is the dominant one is undefined, which could explain why it’s not working.

Comment: I only have one. I've checked there's no duplicate in the code. I've also added a single NSLog in the -objectAtIndex function which would say hello whenever the function is called, it never say hello...

Comment: I've changed the name of the function from objectAtIndex to valueAtIndex and it works. I still don't understand why it worked in a project but not another...